# error while installing node modules for react application

Tags: reactjs, npm

> I'm new to reactjs , while installing the this package I'm getting
>   this following error

```
 npm install  react-router-dom
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: A warning is not an error; you can ignore it.

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'C:\Github project\app1\src'

Comment: Did you try reinstalling react-router-dom?

Comment: yes i tried npm install --save react-router-dom

Comment: Try just `npm install` to install all dependencies in your package.json.

Comment: npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Github project\app1\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink